# Winform Drag Drop into excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I would like to perform drag drop from my winform into Excel. For example, holding a button (or a line in DataGridView) in Winform and drag and drop it into an Excel cell will perfom some action or write some data into the Excel cell.

I am talking about drag drop between winform and Excel, not between winform components.

I remember seeing an example once but could not find it again on Google.

**Update: Following answer by Avantol13,**

How do we extract the object being sent over to Excel ? In the example, it's kind of a hack to let the string be written into the cell, then check that cell's content to perform further action. Perhaps something similar to DragDrop event where we can extract data being sent from e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0])

Besides, using `Application_SheetChange` to know the drop event will cause it to loop as `Application_SheetChange` -> code that modifies the cell, as in the example (delete the cell and write something new) -> trigger again `Application_SheetChange`, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840032(v=office.12).aspx) may be what you're looking for. Slightly out of date, but may still apply to your situation

Comment: Thanks Avantol13. This is what I am looking for. One question: How do we extract the object being sent over to Excel ? In the example, it's kind of a hack to let the string be written into the cell, then check that cell's content to perform further action. Perhaps something similar to DragDrop event where we can extract data being sent from e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0])

Comment: I would update your question with the details you just described, perhaps someone with a better knowledge of this can answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Sean Sexton provides an excellent example](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/07/707-dragging-a-list-of-items-from-a-wpf-application-into-excel/) on how to Drag&Drop data from a WPF window to Excel. I have modified his example so that it works with WinForms.
Try this:

```
private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> stringItems = new List<string>() { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };

    //Separate all values with tabs
    string someValues = string.Join("\t", stringItems);

    DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Text, someValues);
    DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

Comment: This will still send only text as drag object. The fact that it is written into contiguous cells is because the text is comma-separated. I think we cannot however say for example "write in column"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this based on the recommendation by Avantol13.

Hook Excel_Drop event when Excel's sheet is modified

```
Application.SheetChange += new AppEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(Excel_Drop);
```

For the button where the drag initiated:

```
private void _Button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop("Action1", DragDropEffects.All);
            }
        }
```

Another button will send "Action2" as flag.

```
private void Excel_Drop(object dropObj, Range target)
    {
        String dragData = Convert.ToString(target.Value2);

        if (dragData.Equals("Action1"))
        {
            Application.SheetChange -= Excel_Drop;
            DoAction1();
            Application.SheetChange += Excel_Drop;
            return;
        }
        if (dragData.Equals("Action2"))
        {
            Application.SheetChange -= Excel_Drop;
            DoAction2();
            Application.SheetChange += Excel_Drop;
            return;
        }
    }
```

To solve the looping problem :dropping event fires `Excel_drop`->which calls DoActionx() that modifies the sheet again->in turns re-fire `Excel_drop`, I block the event.

There are however still several drawbacks base on this method of using a text flag:

1. I cannot send anything except text as drag object like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx) when dragdrop between winform components. Because of that, I need to let the text flag be sent anyway, delete it and do my action. Beside being a hack, I cannot verify "do action only if the cell is empty" because the drop will overwrite my cell with the flag anyway.
   Any recommendation is welcome.
2. How can we send anything as drag object?